# Android makefiles: inconsistent results from the build system

Tags: android, makefile, android-source, android-build

I have been learning how to write Android makefiles (Android.**mk**) by incorporating various apps into my regular builds of the Android OS (version 5.0.2).

Having successfully converted a simple app, I have moved on to something more challenging like the [**GitHub**](https://github.com/github/android) app that hasn't been receiving much attention on the playstore while its development continues.

The following makefile **successfully** generates a GitHub.apk (*please disregard path shenanigans*):

```
local_path := $(call my-dir)
github_path := external/github
viewpagerindicator_path := external/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator

include $(call all-makefiles-under,$(local_path))

# build the GitHub application
LOCAL_PATH := $(github_path)/app
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := android-support-v4 android-support-v7-appcompat gson
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += com.github.kevinsawicki.wishlist
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += com.viewpagerindicator
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += okhttp
# prebuilt jars
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += com.github.kevinsawicki.http-request
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += guice guice-assistedinject roboguice
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += com.afollestad.materialdialogs
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += org.eclipse.egit.github.core
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += retrofit okio
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += javax.inject

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under,src/main/java)

LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)/res \
    $(viewpagerindicator_path)/library/res \
    prebuilts/sdk/current/support/v7/appcompat/res

LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS += --auto-add-overlay

LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := current
LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := GitHub

LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := disabled

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
```

Unfortunately, attempting to run the installed application on a real device produces the following fatal exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.github.mobile.ui.search.RepositorySearchSuggestionsProvider: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.github.mobile.ui.search.RepositorySearchSuggestionsProvider" on path:
DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.github.mobile-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

As it happens, an older version of this app is available on [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=com.github.mobile).

Using `dexlist` on its `classes.dex` lists **9371** lines, on the package I've built: **1644**, but the intermediate residual `classes.dex` from my build shows: **19333**.

I do not understand why are most of the classes gone, and methods that remain are related to okhttp and okio, as if everything else is being removed upon inclusion into the apk archive.

This is how **Androguard** displays the difference:

```
(mine):
Reflection code: False
Lcom/android/okhttp/internal/Platform; tagSocket ['DALVIK_SYSTEM']
Lcom/android/okhttp/internal/Platform; untagSocket ['DALVIK_SYSTEM']

(com.github.mobile_1900.apk from F-Droid):
Reflection code: True
Landroid/support/v4/app/ActivityCompatHoneycomb; invalidateOptionsMenu ['ANDROID', 'APP']
Landroid/support/v4/app/BackStackRecord; <init> ['ANDROID', 'SUPPORT']
Landroid/support/v4/app/BackStackRecord; doAddOp ['ANDROID', 'SUPPORT']
Landroid/support/v4/app/BackStackRecord; add ['ANDROID', 'SUPPORT']
Landroid/support/v4/app/BackStackRecord; add ['ANDROID', 'SUPPORT']
Landroid/support/v4/app/BackStackRecord; add ['ANDROID', 'SUPPORT']
Landroid/support/v4/app/BackStackRecord; attach ['ANDROID', 'SUPPORT']
Landroid/support/v4/app/BackStackRecord; bumpBackStackNesting ['ANDROID', 'UTIL']
(... skipped large amount of lines ...)
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated!